# Dynamically change format settings

Tags: views, hooks

I'm trying to alter a Drupal view format settings dynamically, and I am currently using the following code.

```
 function mymodulenamehere_views_pre_render(&$view) {
   if ($view->name == 'view_name_here') {
     $view->display['panel_pane_5']->display_options['defaultView'] = 'Setting here' ;
   }
 }
```

This doesn't change anything. I can manually alter the view and the changes I want work. I can then look at the changes through features and see the line of code required, which I then use in `hook_views_pre_render()` as above.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want that? Why can't you simply set what you want for the view with given name? Also, there is this proverb: *"It's always caching"*

Comment: Yep true after further investigation, I found that with the current setup up we are suing with panels I could conditionally switch the view to be shown. 

I have at least after this tried all the different hooks and have a better understanding. Thanks for the comment.